# Where are nmcli capitalized setting stored and how can I modify them?

Tags: networking, centos, configuration

I have a VM and I'm playing with `nmcli` on CentOS 8

`nmcli` shows a couple addresses which I added.  I was able to remove the `.106` address from the `ipv4.addresses`, but not from the capitalized configuration (I don't know what the capitalized component config is called).

```
$ nmcli connection show enp0s8
...
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.56.107/24
...
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.56.107/24
IP4.ADDRESS[2]:                         192.168.56.106/24
```

`nmcli` still shows both addresses are active

```
$ nmcli
enp0s8: connected to enp0s8
"Intel 82540EM"
ethernet (e1000), 08:00:27:42:77:8C, hw, mtu 1500
inet4 192.168.56.107/24
inet4 192.168.56.106/24
route4 192.168.56.0/24
route4 192.168.56.0/24
route4 192.168.56.0/24
inet6 fe80::f3b6:f5e9:b207:49a1/64
route6 fe80::/64
route6 ff00::/8
```

As does `ip route`

```
$ ip address show enp0s8
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:42:77:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.56.106/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s8
   valid_lft 333sec preferred_lft 333sec
inet 192.168.56.107/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute enp0s8
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::f3b6:f5e9:b207:49a1/64 scope link noprefixroute
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The configuration does not appear in the network scripts

```
$ egrep "106" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*
$
```

My question, with this context is, where is the capitalized config stored and how can I modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "settings" appearing in all capital letters are not settings, but represent the actual current state of the connection. You do not "modify" them because they are not settings. Rather, if you want to change the live connection, you use the existing tools (e.g. `ip addr del 192.168.56.106 dev enp8s0`) to do so.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess what I'm not able to understand is where at address is being added to the interface.

Comment: @BobSmith The `ip a` output says that it is `dynamic`, e.g. assigned via DHCP.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Wow, I feel pretty dumb now, but happy to know the issue; even if it should have been obvious.